# grep - only show X chars in the result

Tags: grep

Is there a way to instruct `grep` to cut results after **X** chars?

E.g. if I execute `grep -iR searchString` then sometimes there are compressed javascript files in the result where the whole code is in one line and this "destroys" the result because there is sometimes too much content for my terminal to handle and parts of the result dissapears or I have to scroll much.

e.g. the result should change from...

```
123456789
```

...to...

```
1234
```

...if I execute grep with the pseudo option `--show-n-chars 4`.

I searched in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) but I was unable to find something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` itself has no such option. You can achieve your goal with the `cut` command:

```
grep "foo" bar | cut -c -4
```

This will only print the first 4 chars of every `grep` result.

Answer (score 6):

You could use option `-o` to only print the matching part in combination with `-E` (extended regular expression) 
and pattern `.{0,4}` to match up to four characters *after* your search pattern:

```
$ echo "foo123456789" | grep -oE 'foo.{0,4}'
foo1234
```

Or you could pipe the result to `head -cN` (similar to `cut`) to print `N` characters:

```
$ echo "foo123456789" | grep 'foo' | head -c4
foo1
```

Comment: I prefer this answer, because it uses the tool the op wanted to use.